# Why do I get IDBObserver is not defined?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I am trying to experiment with IndexedDB Observables in Chrome.

According to [the sample page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/indexeddb-observers/) they are available in Chrome 57+.  I am on Chrome 84.  Using the sample page linked, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: IDBObserver is not defined (Your browser may not support this feature.)`  I have similar issues with my own code.

What do I need to do to use IDBObserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observers are an experimental feature only available behind a flag, as noted in the sample page you link to. Are you enabling the flag, either via the command line or chrome://flags/ ?

Comment: Doh, everywhere I looked at this I missed the bit about the flag!